# Endpoint URL has an invalid value

Tags: botframework

I am trying to register my Bot at https://dev.botframework.com

> However, when I put https://localhost:44338/api/messages in the
>   Messaging endpoint field I get an error - Endpoint URL has an invalid
>   value. My bot is running locally on https://localhost:44338.
>
> Also is there any way I can create my own web client which can
>   communicate with my Bot.
>
> Is Bot Registration mandatory for it to be deployed in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to register your bot with your local instance whereas you need to use a deployed (production) instance.

Publish your bot to Azure and use the URL you get from that. In Visual Studio you can right click your project and select "Publish"- just follow the instructions from there.

You can make your own client, yes. You can use your browser or anything else to make HTTP requests to your production bot.

You need to register your bot if you're using the bot connector.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there any example of web client which does not need any bot connector.

Comment: FYI - You can register your bot and still use your local instance if you use ngrok.